# unable to set mapreduce.job.reduces through generic option parser

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, google-compute-engine

```
hadoop jar MapReduceTryouts-1.jar invertedindex.simple.MyDriver -D mapreduce.job.reduces=10 /user/notprabhu2/Input/potter/ /user/notprabhu2/output
```

I have been trying in vain to set the number of reducers through the -D option provided by GenericOptionParser but it does not seem to work and I have no idea why.

I tried `-D mapreduce.job.reduces=10`(with space after -D) and also

`-Dmapreduce.job.reduces=10`(without space after -D) but nothing seems to dodge.

In my Driver class I have implemented Tools.

```
package invertedindex.simple;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class MyDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = getConf();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);

        job.setJarByClass(MyDriver.class);

        Path outputPath =  new Path(args[1]);
        outputPath.getFileSystem(getConf()).delete(outputPath, true);

        job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);

        job.setNumReduceTasks(3);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(),new MyDriver(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }

}
```

Since I have explicitly set the number of reducers to 3 in my driver code I always end up with 3 reducers.

I am using `CDH 5.4.7` which has `Hadoop 2.6.0` on a 2 node cluster on Google Compute Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Turned out to be so silly but still posting the answer just in case someone also does the same silly mistake.

Seems the `job.setNumReduceTasks(3);` line in my driver class is taking precedence over the `-D mapreduce.job.reduces=10` in the command line.

When I removed the`job.setNumReduceTasks(3);` line from my code everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

set the property for number of reducers - mapreduce.job.reduces in xml tag

set property in mapred-site.xml which will be called by code from configuration:

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.reduces</name>
    <value>5</value>
</property>
```

relaunch hadoop process